# Differences between MySQL Cluster OSS and CGE editions

Tags: mysql

What are the differences between the [OSS](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/cluster/) and [CGE](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/clustercge/) editions of MySQL Cluster?

Is CGE the OSS edition plus additional tools (Cluster Manager, Enterprise Backup, Enterprise Monitor, Workbench Standard Edition), or are there also differences in the MySQL Cluster app between the two editions as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the core features are available in the GPL version.

Besides support, the commercial version includes non-free [management tools](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/features.html).

Comment: Is there any version of MySsql cluster CGE for ubuntu? Or is there any alternative to MySql cluster GPL, I don't want to use GPL version of MySql cluster, I am using Mysql queries at the backend and very new to clustering concepts, my question is, is there any cluster which supports MySql queries?

Comment: Please ask a new question, and describe your problem with NDB precisely (e.g. what is a "MySQL query"? By definition, MySQL Cluster obviously supports MySQL queries).